# ChromeDriver Setup On MAC M1 chip, Version: 12.4

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, driver

from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("/Users/aseempathak/Downloads/chromedriver") # Enter Location of Chrome
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

Install Selenium and Chrome Driver:

**pip3 install selenium      **
*Requirement already satisfied: selenium in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.8.0)*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck?